# windows application with web access to database

Tags: sql-server, web-services, web-applications, windows

I want to write several programs with the same database. I have two solutions:

1. developing programs as windows application and using web service for access to share database. (may it cause, the speed of windows applications down or not?)
2. developing programs as web application

which way is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which way is better

Which is preferable depends upon the requirements you're developing the applications to.

If your users are on a variety of platforms (Windows, OSX, Mobile devices), or you don't want to deal with application deployment problems then a Web application may be best.

If you need to access features of the operating system (client side processing, data storage, etc) - then you may need to use a deployed application.

You should look at what the requirements are more closely, which will give you the answer.